# Android: How do I make a single retrofit call in which it will display on different tabs , tablayout?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm creating an android app in which I will display photos in the tab layout. The requirement should only be 20 photos in each tab. How do I display the photos on the tab? I'm using viewpager and on my current code. Btw, this is the site that I used for my data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Thanks!

Adapter:

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
List<Photos> photosList = new ArrayList<>();


public PhotoAdapter(Context mContext, List<Photos> photosList){
    this.photosList = photosList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.photo_card, viewGroup, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    Photos photos = photosList.get(i);
    Log.i("Position: ", i+1 + " Id: " + photos.getId());
    myViewHolder.mTitleTextView.setText(photos.getTitle());
    myViewHolder.mIdTextView.setText(photos.getId());
    String thumbnail = photos.getUrl();

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(thumbnail)
            .into(myViewHolder.mUrlImageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return photosList.size();
    return 20;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mTitleTextView, mIdTextView;
    ImageView mUrlImageView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        mIdTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
        mUrlImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);

    }
}
```

Fragment: (Dynamic)

```
public class DyanamicFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public List<Photos> photos = new ArrayList<>();

public static DyanamicFragment newInstance(){
    return new DyanamicFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_fragment_layout, container, false);
    initViews(view);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.PhotosRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),4));


    return view;
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.commonTextView);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf("Category: " +getArguments().getInt("position")));

    loadJSON();
}

private void loadJSON(){
    Service serviceAPI = Client.getClient();
    Call<JsonArray> loadPhotosCall = serviceAPI.readPhotosArray();

    loadPhotosCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {
            try {
                String photosString = response.body().toString();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Photos>>() {}.getType();
                photos = getPhotosListFromJson(photosString, listType);

                mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(getContext(), photos));
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}


public static <T> List<T> getPhotosListFromJson(String jsonString, Type type){
    if (!isValid(jsonString)){
        return null;
    }
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
}

public static boolean isValid(String json){
    try {
        new JsonParser().parse(json);
        return true;
    }catch (JsonSyntaxException jse){
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initView();
}

private void initView() {

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    setDynamicFragmentToTabLayout();
}

private void setDynamicFragmentToTabLayout() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i == 1){
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Photos: 1-20"));
        }
        if (i == 2){
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Photos: 21-40"));
        }
        if (i == 3){
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Photos: 41-60"));
        }
        if (i == 4){
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Photos: 61-80"));
        }
        if (i == 5){
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Photos: 81-100"));
        }
    }
    DynamicFragmentAdapter mDynamicFragmentAdapter = new DynamicFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mDynamicFragmentAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
}
```

Comment: @PateOrtega can you please add the ViewPager Code also.

Comment: @MohitAjwani already add.

Comment: You are not selecting page wise items anywhere. For example, when you are adding the Fragment `adapter.addFragment(new PhotoTab2Fragment(), "21-40");` You are only setting Tab Title. You need to iterate page wise and add 20 items to the list that need to be shown. Adding Fragment should happen only on condition if the list has items more than one page. Also, you should not use while loop in `onBindViewHolder` method, it will block your UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the api call in the fragment or activity that has the view pager.

Then you can parse the response and set the required image data for each fragment when adding it to the view pager. 
The fragments can then display the data that has been set to its list.